# popup menu in header gets pushed back behind page content

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a menu button in the header.  The page gets populated by an ajax request.  Clicking on the menu button, it appears for a second on the screen and then gets pushed back behind the listview.  I coudldn't find a solution to this anywhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="./js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
      <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
        <a data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-rel="popup" href="#popupMenu" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
    </div>
   <!--Menu-->
     <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:200px;" data-theme="d">
         <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Share</a></li>
         <li data-icon="false"><a href="mailto:" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Contact</a></li>
         <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Оцени Нас</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <!--Menu-->
<div data-role="content">
  <ul>
    //dynamically populated data here
  </u>
</div>
<script src="js/getmainnews.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The same thing happens on another page where the popup gets cut off a little by the header.  I'm not sure if I need to show you the JS file...it's just a ajax call on('pageinit'...) and refreshes the listviews at the end.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try setting the `z-index` on the menu button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a z-index to the menu.

```
 element {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 9999; 
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget you need the element to be positioned (relative, fixed/absolute) in order to use `z-index`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the z-index.  I'll look into it now.  Would I just include that in the css file?  In my Android Emulator, the menu doesn't get pushed back.  Running it on my phone pushes it back.

Comment: Got it...I just didn't know what to search for.  Here's what I added to my css:  .ui-popup { -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) } and it worked on my phone.  Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Thanks user2025469. Your solution fixed my problem with jQuery Mobile popups on android browser!